# Problemas con el paquete "tidyverse"

Tags: r, rstudio, tidyverse

quisiera ayuda, necesito instalar "tiddyverse" y me sale esto
"Package LibPath Version Priority Depends Imports LinkingTo Suggests Enhances License License_is_FOSS
License_restricts_use OS_type Archs MD5sum NeedsCompilation Built"

Alguien sabe como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Por el error,  trata de un error tipográfico a la hora de instalar el paquete, estás haciendo:

```
installed.packages()
```

Cuando deberías invocar:

```
install.packages()
```

Son dos funciones que difieren en dos letras pera hacen cosas muy distintas, aún siendo un error de tipeo, suele ser un error bastante típico y no muy evidente, por eso me animo a dejar una respuesta.